# Ellipse passing through two given points

Tags: conic-sections, coordinate-systems

Find the equation of ellipse passing through the points (3,4) and(5,1).
Are there finite no of ellipse passing through the points?

Comment: Even for circles it is infinite number for only two points.. visualize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Five points define a conic**, you don't have enough information to define an ellipse unless it is restricted to standard form:
>
> $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

Substituting your points $A(3,4)$ and $B(5,1)$ gives $15x^2+16y^2=391$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The equation of an ellipse referred to its symmetry axis contains two parameters ( do you know ?), so if we know the coordinates of two points we can write two equations and find the two parameters.